# How do I obtain all the GET parameters on Silex?

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I've been using Silex for a day, and I have the first "stupid" question. If I have:

```
$app->get('/cities/{city_id}.json', function(Request $request, $city_id) use($app) {
    ....
})
->bind('city')
->middleware($checkHash);
```

I want to get all the parameters (city_id) included in the middleware:

```
$checkHash = function (Request $request) use ($app) {

    // not loading city_id, just the parameter after the ?
    $params = $request->query->all();

    ....
}
```

So, how do I get city_id (both the parameter name and its value) inside the middleware. I'm going to have like 30 actions, so I need something usable and maintainable.

What am I missing?

thanks a lot!

**Solution**

We need to get those extra parameters of *$request->attributes*

```
$checkHash = function (Request $request) use ($app) {

    // GET params
    $params = $request->query->all();

    // Params which are on the PATH_INFO
    foreach ( $request->attributes as $key => $val )
    {
        // on the attributes ParamaterBag there are other parameters
        // which start with a _parametername. We don't want them.
        if ( strpos($key, '_') != 0 )
        {
            $params[ $key ] = $val;
        }
    }

    // now we have all the parameters of the url on $params

    ...

});
```

Comment: it looks like ->middleware() doesn't exist anymore?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In [Request](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) object you have access to multiple parameter bags, in particular:

- `$request->query` - the GET parameters
- `$request->request` - the POST parameters
- `$request->attributes` - the request attributes (includes parameters parsed from the PATH_INFO)

`$request->query` contains GET parameters only. `city_id` is not a GET parameter. It's an attribute parsed from the PATH_INFO.

Silex uses several [Symfony Components](http://symfony.com/components). Request and Response classes are part of the HttpFoundation. Learn more about it from Symfony docs:

- [The HttpFoundation Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html)
- [HttpFoundation API](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation.html)
- [Request API](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html)

Comment: thanks kuba, you pointed me to the solution. I've added it to the question.

Comment: One remark. Always use strict comparators with strpos ("!==" and not "!="). Remember than null and 0 are "equal" when compared with == (but are not equal compared with ===).